# git-svn checkout checks files out to wrong folder

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

At work we have an svn repository that uses a somewhat standard folder structure that looks like the following:

```
remote-repo/
   tags/
   branches/
      branch_to_proj1_A/
         proj_1_1
         proj_1_2
   trunk/
      proj1/
         proj1_A/
            proj1_1
            proj1_2
      proj2/
      proj3/
```

After I do a git-svn clone (using the -s option) I get the following checked out folder structure

```
local-gitsvn/
   proj1/
      proj1_A/
         proj1_1
         proj1_2
   proj2/
   proj3/
```

Now I'm interested in working with the svn branch 'branch_to_proj1_A' that someone else created. Looks like this is a branch for only the folder proj1_A... thus I do

```
$ git-svn checkout -b local-branch_to_proj1_A branch_to_proj1_A
```

After checkout, I have the following folder structure in the git repo

```
local-gitsvn/
   proj1_A/
      proj1_1
      proj1_2
```

Note that the rest of the projects are gone, and only proj1_A is there.

My question is, is it possible to checkout the branch to the right folder? So that after the 'git svn checkout' I get the same folder structure as in the original cloned repo?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't care about synching back to svn, you could do subtree merge:

Having trunk/master (or some more specific revision) checked out:

`git subtree merge --prefix=proj1/proj1_A branch_to_proj1_A`

after successful merge you'll have changes from branch_to_proj1_A merged into the full directory.